# Debian 10 (Buster) - Asking to choose the app every time I open a pdf file

Tags: linux, debian

In Debian 10 (Buster), every time I want to open some file within file manager I must select an application. Even if I check the box that says "Remember application association for all files of type...".

[image: Choose Application - Dolphin]

How do I get rid of this message?

Comment: What is your question?